# paying users vs paid users vs premium users

Tags: word-choice

paying users vs paid users vs premium users

I'm building website's member system 
and want to know which is the best and correct one.

Thanks

Comment: Customer-facing or internal-facing term? Who is your public? You obviously can't call them _revenue units" in their face, while it's merely a bad idea to do so internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paying users and premium users are both correct, although I believe the latter is more common. Paid users implies that you are paying them, rather than the other way around.